# Fade in from 98% Black (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, image-filter

Is it possible to do a fade in effect with ffmpeg that fades in from 98% black? In other words, you very slightly see what is underneath the solid black at frame 0?

I can use this command, but the problem is that it fades in from 100% black. I would like to be able to set it to an arbitrary percentage.

```
-filter_complex "fade=t=in:st=0:d=4"
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The start time `st` represents the timestamp at which the video should be fully blank. The duration `d` represents the timestamp interval over which the filter will interpolate the video to fully visible. So, in order to start from 98% black and get to full visibility at 4 seconds, calculate what timestamp should the fade start so the first frame has 98% black.

So, rate of opacity change = 4.0/98 ~= 0.0408s. So, if the fade started at -0.0816s and ended at 4s, then the frame at 0 would be 98% faded. So, the fade would be

```
fade=t=in:st=-0.0816:d=4.0816
```

However, there's a small hitch in this particular case. The `st` can't be negative. So, the workaround is to offset the timestamps before and after the fade.

```
setpts=PTS+1/TB,fade=t=in:st=0.9183:d=4.0816,setpts=PTS-1/TB
```

The fade `st` has to also be offset to account for the temporarily new timestamps.